# Implementing a static counter every program run

Tags: java

I'm doing a simple card game of lucky 9, I want the counter to increment so I can record the number of wins for each player, I already declared the winCount as static but every time I hit the run program the counter outputs either 1 or 0;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Tester {

static int p1WinCount;
static int p2WinCount;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Tester test = new Tester();

    String player1 = "PLAYER 1";
    int p1r1 = rand.nextInt(13)+1;
    int p1s1 = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    int p1r2 = rand.nextInt(13)+1;
    int p1s2 = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    int p1total = test.total(test.convRank1(p1r1), test.convRank2(p1r2));

    System.out.println(player1);
    System.out.printf("Card 1: %s of %s\n", test.getRank(p1r1), test.getSuit(p1s1));
    System.out.printf("Card 2: %s of %s\n", test.getRank(p1r2), test.getSuit(p1s2));
    System.out.printf("Card Total: %d\n", p1total);

    System.out.println();

    String player2 = "PLAYER 2";
    int p2r1 = rand.nextInt(13)+1;
    int p2s1 = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    int p2r2 = rand.nextInt(13)+1;
    int p2s2 = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    int p2total = test.total(test.convRank1(p2r1), test.convRank2(p2r2));

    System.out.println(player2);
    System.out.printf("Card 1: %s of %s\n", test.getRank(p2r1), test.getSuit(p2s1));
    System.out.printf("Card 2: %s of %s\n", test.getRank(p2r2), test.getSuit(p2s2));
    System.out.printf("Card Total: %d\n", p2total);

    System.out.println();

    if(p1total > p2total) {
        System.out.println("PLAYER 1 IS THE WINNER");
        p1WinCount++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("PLAYER 2 IS THE WINNER");
        p2WinCount++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Player 1 wins %d times / Player 2 wins %d times", p1WinCount, p2WinCount);
}

public String getRank(int x) {
    switch(x) {
    case 1:
        return "ACE";
    case 2:
        return "TWO";
    case 3:
        return "THREE";
    case 4:
        return "FOUR";
    case 5:
        return "FIVE";
    case 6:
        return "SIX";
    case 7:
        return "SEVEN";
    case 8:
        return "EIGHT";
    case 9:
        return "NINE";
    case 10:
        return "TEN";
    case 11:
        return "JACK";
    case 12:
        return "QUEEN";
    case 13:
        return "KING";
    } return null;
}

public String getSuit(int x) {
    switch(x) {
    case 1:
        return "DIAMOND";
    case 2:
        return "CLUBS";
    case 3:
        return "HEARTS";
    case 4:
        return "SPADE";
    } return null;
}

public int convRank1(int x) {
    if(x > 9) {
        return x - 9;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}

public int convRank2(int x) {
    if(x > 9) {
        return x - 9;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}

public int total(int x, int y) {
    if(x + y > 9) {
        return x + y - 9;
    } else {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

}

here is the output:

```
PLAYER 1
Card 1: FIVE of SPADE
Card 2: QUEEN of SPADE
Card Total: 8

PLAYER 2
Card 1: FOUR of SPADE
Card 2: ACE of CLUBS
Card Total: 5

PLAYER 1 IS THE WINNER

Player 1 wins 1 times / Player 2 wins 0 times
```

Comment: you can refer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403031/scope-of-static-variable-and-methods-in-java

Comment: a good read.. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to store/persist the count to a file or database (disk memory), just declaring static counter does NOT preserve data over multiple runs**

The static counter (in fact all program variables) will only be in main memory (RAM) during the program execution (run) and will NOT be available once program run terminates. So when you start the program again, it will be a fresh run and you can't get the previous runs data.

Comment: oh no, I'm still a couple of chapters away from I/O, i'll just discard the win count for now and get back to it once I'm done with the I/O chapter, thank you for your answer, really appreciate it..

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are cleared once the program is finished. You would have to have your program write the win count of each player to a file, or keep running (add a restart button) once someone wins. Static variables do not last past the life of the program, they simply do not belong to an object.